# How to set width correctly in CSS - Need to fix bug with Safari on Mac and on iPad

Tags: html, ios, css, macos, safari

i'm making page http://www.rhemapress.pl/www_physis/index.php?id=1. As you see header background is on 100% width (orange). It's first element in `<body>`. Code for this is: `<div id="header"></div>`. And CSS for this element is:

```
#header {
width: 100%;
height: 174px;
background-image: url("img/top-line.jpg");
position: absolute;
z-index: 6; 
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

It's ok on Safari on Mac. When i use Safari on iPad, header isn't set correctly - it's not 100% width.

Where's the problem? Could you help me with it?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish vs. what it's not doing correctly.

Comment: I would like the width of the element `header` was 100% on iPad

Comment: @kinakuta on the iPad the orange is not taking up 100%, on his website in a web browser on the computer it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for answers. I think it's not possible to do this correctly, but if I in mistake then respond this with correct answer. I moved `#header` background to `<body>` in CSS and set `repeat-x`. Now it's working correctly but it's does not solve the problem with `100% width` of element on notebook and mobile device (ipad).

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting after looking at your code that you need the meta viewport tag..

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but the problem is: ipad screen is 1024px width. Page is builded for 1280px screen. When i set `device-width` or get `document.body.offsetWidth` by jQuery, that return me 1024, not 1280 :/

Comment: I was looking through your resets and your padding still exists on #header. As I don't have an IPad with me and can't see how much area is around the #header, that would be my next guess.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

to your `<head></head>`

Comment: geez, i posted this answer on 2 other questions which had nothing to do with this. That is the downside of having multiple stackoverflow pages open.